# Can't get positions of QGraphicsItems in scene

Tags: qt, position, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to get the positions of the graphicsitems in the scene.
But their `QPointF` value always remains (0,0).

I am painting when mouse-click event occurs. On debugging `scene->items()`, I get

`(QGraphicsItem(this =0x22edff0, parent =0x0, pos =QPointF(0, 0) , z = 0 , flags = ( ) ) )`

for each graphics item in scene but with different memory address.

This is my *mainwindow.cpp* code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  scene = new QGraphicsScene;
  view = new QGraphicsView;
  view->setScene(scene);
  button = new QPushButton("Item");
  QGridLayout  *layout = new QGridLayout;
  layout->addWidget(button);
  layout->addWidget(view);
  setLayout(layout);
  connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(createItem()));
}

void MainWindow::createItem()
{
  myEntity = new Item;
  scene->addItem(myEntity);
  count_items();
}

void MainWindow::count_items()
{
  qDebug() << scene->items().count();
  qDebug() << scene->items();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{}
```

This is my *item.cpp* code:

```
#include "item.h"
Item::Item()
{
  ClickFlag = true;
  PaintFlag = false;
} 
Item::~Item(){}

QRectF Item::boundingRect() const
{
  // outer most edges
  return QRectF(0,0,1450,1400);
}
void Item::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton){
    if(ClickFlag){
        x = event->pos().x();
        y = event->pos().y();
        PaintFlag = true;
        ClickFlag = false;
       }
   }
}

void Item::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                              QWidget *widget)
{
  if(PaintFlag){
    QPen paintPen;
    paintPen.setWidth(4);
    pt.setX(x);
    pt.setY(y);
    painter->setPen(paintPen);
    painter->drawPoint(x,y);
    update();              
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find the position of these items correctly.

Comment: You never invoke `QGraphicsItem::setPos` on your items, which allow to set the position of your items in their belonging scene. Quite normal that their default position remains zero, even if your are painting at another point in the graphicsItem referential

Comment: I have looked into `setPos()` function but where do I use it? I could not figure it out.

Comment: You can read all about coordinate system in qgraphicsview framework [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/graphicsview.html#id-a93690a1-04f1-42c1-8bdf-90819fca8982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is supposed to be implemented in another way. For example:

1. Use `QGraphicsScene::addEllipse` to add small ellipse (which will look like a point) to the scene. Save the pointer to it in a class variable. The ellipse itself should be at the center, e.g. `(-1, -1, 2, 2)`.
2. Reimplement `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent`, detect mouse clicks and call `setPos` for the ellipse item (or add new ellipse each time and immediately call `setPos` if you need multiple points).
3. Use `QGraphicsItem::pos` to get previously set positions.

Reimplementing `QGraphicsItem::paint` is usually an over-complication. Qt have plenty of item classes for all common needs. Just build your scene from geometric primitives, pixmaps, etc.